# Is there a Correlation metric for Categorical vs Numerical features?

Tags: correlation, descriptive-statistics, pearson-r, association-measure, cramers-v

I've been searching for some time for a correlation metric analogous to the Pearson correlation value for numerical vs numerical features, or Cramér's V for categorical vs categorical features, but this time for **categorical** vs **numerical** features.

This is my toy data example in Python, where the categorical variable is **not** ordinal and notice that the number of observations per class of the categorical feature is not the same:

```
pd.DataFrame({'numerical': np.array([19, 27, 31, 26, 39, 43, 32, 29, 19, 19, 27, 31]), 
              'categorical': np.array(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'])})
```

I've seen a lot of answers referring Interclass Correlation (but I don't have a square matrix and also I don't have *subjects being analysed by several judges...*). Also, I've seen that the use of one-way ANOVA is also frequent, but it does not solve the problem because it does not translate in a clear strength of association coefficient as Pearson.

Can you suggest a metric or it is impossible to have one for this case?

Comment: As written this doesn't make much sense to me. Correlation by definition assumes that there is a paired ordering between your variables. So if $X$ increases, then $Y$ tends to increase too, *when considered simultaneously*. In your example, I don't see any indication of such a pairing: you just have a list of categorical variables along with their values. So what do you mean by correlation here?

Comment: @AlexR. For instance, Cramér's V does not assume any ordering (right?) and nevertheless it is an association metric. I was wondering if there is something like it for this case.

Comment: Cramer's V also has *simultaneous* pairings. It looks at $n_{ij}$ which is the number of occurances of $(A_i,B_j)$. Again, if you want to understand associations between two variables, you need to look at their joint occurrences, which is not clear from your setup.

Comment: Ok. I hope to made it clear now. It is pairwise occurances

Comment: Cramér's V is for two nominal variables.